# get position of a webview on the screen using javascript in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a webview in my android app. How can I find div position according to the screen (the webview may be outside the screen or only partially on the screen). I know I can ask the native code using "addJavascriptInterface", but i want to do it using only the javascript code. can it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

No it cannot be done. A webview doesn't have any access to information about layout in your application. Best solution would be to expose required information via native interface as you mentioned.